# Fitting many models in for loop using R

Tags: r

I wanted to create a list of models that will be used to fit my data.

Code Below

```
models = list("naiveBayes","rf")

for(model_name in models){
  print(model_name)
  formual = V35 ~ .
  model = model_name(formual,data=train)
}
```

The error I get 
`Error: could not find function "model_name"`

Comment: given that `model_name` is a string and not a function, what made you think that this would work? Also, did you look at the `caret` package? it's tailor made to help do things like this. Also, `rf` is ambiguous since there's a `stats::rf()` but `rf` is naming shorthand in the `caret` package. also, `model` is only ever going to hold the last model since you're not making a list.

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes. I just wanted to give an example and `caret package` does not have the models I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a variable that is the function:

```
models = c("naiveBayes","rf")

for(model_name in models){
  print(model_name)
  formual = V35 ~ .
  m <- match.fun(model_name)
  m(formual,data=train)
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, this code is pretty handy! Does anyone know how to do predictions based on the output of this code?

Also how does this code cater to different model arguments?

Comment: This code does not have output, you need to store the model result in a variable, then use this model variable for prediction of new samples. If you want to pass different model arguments to the model function, you can put the arguments in a list object and use it in the loop. So besides the `models` vector you will have another object `params` which is a list of lists. Each list consists of the parameters you want to pass to the specific model funcion. For a better answer you could make a new question, with an example.